# select one producttype, and in other list show data from product that I select . Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have some web method that I get from ws. Also I have one web method that I get product Type. I want to select one product Type,for example, I select product Type Sensor, when I select this, in other form I want to show my all sensor list.

My code ts, for get my all data:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ws.getAllProductType().subscribe(
      producttype => {
        this.producttype = producttype.map((producttypee) => {
          return new ProductType(producttypee); // Return all product Type
        });
      }
    );
    this.ws.getAllSensor().subscribe(
      sensor=> {
        this.sensor= sensor; // all sensor
      }
    )
    this.gs.getAllGpss().subscribe(
      gps => {
        this.gps = gps; //all gps
      }
    )}
```

My html code

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
      <select formControlName="product_type_id" id="product_type_id" materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="producttype">
        <option value="" disabled selected>ProductType*</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of producttype; let i=index;" [value]="item.product_type_id">{{item.product_type_name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Like this html code, I want to display sensor and gps. When I select Sensor in productType, in other list I want to display sensors, and when I select GPS in productType, in other list I want to display gps.

Can you suggest me some idea?

Comment: you can use ng-repeat in <li> tag. and gps and sensor list are saperate dom object. If you have not got what I said, I can write code for you as well. Let me know.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm waiting for your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code will be like this.

It may have any syntax error as you have not provide me plnkr sample of your code.

```
<!-- Lets say 1 is for Sensor -->
<div *ngIf="producttype.product_type_id == '1'">
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let s of sensor">
        {{s.name}}
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- Lets say 2 is for GPS -->
<div *ngIf="producttype.product_type_id == '2'">
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let g of gps">
        {{g.name}}
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="input-field col s12" >
      <select formControlName="product_id"  *ngIf="item.product_type_id === '123'" id="product_id" materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="sensor">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Produkt*</option>
        <option *ngFor="let s of sensor; let i=index;" [value]="s.sensors_id">{{s.sensor_serial}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

Comment: I write something else but this show me 'product_type_id' of undefined

Comment: try this `*ngIf="product_type_id == '1'"` instead of `*ngIf="producttype.product_type_id == '1'"`

Comment: hmm, when I change it, in html doesn't show my form select, 
though i choose sensor. *ngIf doesn't work well

Comment: @Lonna, sorry for my delayed reply.
Check I have made plnkr, see if it helps.
https://plnkr.co/edit/vcVyEw3dY2S7IARDCH8Z?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, it is really very helpful.

Comment: @Lonna, No Problem. I think you should read about reactive forms in angular from its official website.